# Unable to connect to couchbase from jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, connection, driver, couchbase

I am trying to query couchbase from within JMeter in mac.

I downloaded connector-couchbase-10.0.2.jar. I put the jar file in the jmeter lib folder. I have the couchbase URL of my org and I can connect to it and query it directly.

I put the couchbase uRL in the jmeter JDBC Connector Configuration element. However, it is not clear what to put in the JDBC Driver class.

I keep getting the error message "“Cannot load JDBC driver class”. Any idea what should I do? Is there a way to add the couchbase connector through the JMeter Plugins Manager?

I appreciate any clues to this.

Answer (score 1):

Add also connector's [dependencies](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.teiid.connectors/connector-couchbase/10.0.2/source-code) to JMeter's lib folder

> Dependencies teiid-api, teiid-common-core, jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec, couchbase-api, java-client,

Use `JDBC Driver` as `cdata.jdbc.couchbase.CouchbaseDriver`, see [couchbase JDBC docs](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/CKF/jdbc/pg_connectionj.htm)

> Provide the JDBC URL. For example:

> jdbc:couchbase:User='myusername';Password='mypassword';Server='http://couchbase40'

> or

> jdbc:cdata:couchbase:User='myusername';Password='mypassword';Server='http://couchbase40'

Comment: Actually, I already have all of the above files in the lib folder. I replaced them again just in case. I tried using two ways: HTTP Request with HTTP authorization Manager. This gives me the error message: Non HTTP response message: Socket closed. The other way is using JDBC Request with JDBC Connection Configuration. In the jdbc connection configuration, it is not clear what exactly should I put in fields "JDBC Driver class" and "Database URL". The JDBC request gave the error: "Cannot load JDBC driver class..."

Comment: @NajiShaban use `cdata.jdbc.couchbase.CouchbaseDriver` see more info on http://cdn.cdata.com/help/CKF/jdbc/pg_connectionj.htm

Comment: @NajiShaban if following link didn't work edit your question with full exception